# Loguru - how to change the logs 'filename'

Tags: python, loguru

With the python log library 'loguru', is there a way to change the log file name after declaring it?

Thanks!

```
from loguru import logger

logger.add('dummy.log', format="{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss} {level} {message}")
.....
# How to change log filename?
logger.debug('my message')
```

Answer (score 1):

In loguru, the `add` method returns a logger id, which can be used to remove a logger that is no longer useful (with the `remove` method). This is mentioned [here in the documentation](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru#no-handler-no-formatter-no-filter-one-function-to-rule-them-all).
This translates as:

```py
from loguru import logger


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dummy_logger_id: int = logger.add("dummy.log", format="{time:DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss} {level} {message}")
    logger.info("Only dummy")
    test_logger_id: int = logger.add("test.log", format="{time:DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss} {level} {message}")
    logger.info("Both")
    logger.remove(dummy_logger_id)
    logger.info("Only test")
```

This results in two files, `dummy.log` and `test.log`:
`dummy.log`

```
15-07-2022 08:15:12 INFO Only dummy
15-07-2022 08:15:12 INFO Both
```

`test.log`

```
15-07-2022 08:15:12 INFO Both
15-07-2022 08:15:12 INFO Only test
```